# MVC3 C# Entity Framework populate textbox based off dropdownlist selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Couple of links I've tried, that led me to my code... which isn't working :D

[Get The Drop on DropDownLists](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists) and 
[Creating Cascading Dropdown Lists](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx)

I am trying to allow the user to select a part number (itemnmbr) from a dropdown list and upon their selection, have the page refresh the part description (itemdesc) textbox with the correct value.  Below is the closest I've gotten.

**VIEW CODE:**

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ITEMNMBR").change(function () {
            $.get("/PartsLabor/GetPartDesc", $(this).val(), function (data) {
                $("#ITEMDESC").val(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add part to call: @ViewBag.CALLNBR</legend>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ITEMNMBR, "Item Number")
            @Html.DropDownList("ITEMNMBR", (SelectList) ViewBag.Items, "Please Select a Part #")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ITEMNMBR)
        <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ITEMDESC, "Description")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ITEMDESC)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ITEMDESC)
        <br />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Add Part" />

    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult PCreate(string call)
    {

        var q = db.IV00101.Select(i => new { i.ITEMNMBR});
        ViewBag.Items = new SelectList(q.AsEnumerable(), "ITEMNMBR", "ITEMNMBR");
        ViewBag.CALLNBR = call;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetPartDesc(char itemnmbr)
    {
        var iv101 = db.IV00101.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ITEMNMBR.Contains(itemnmbr));
        string desc = iv101.ITEMDESC;
        return Content(desc);
    }
```

Firefox Error Console returns:

> Timestamp: 12/28/2012 2:40:29 PM Warning: Use of attributes' specified
>   attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. Source File:
>   http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js Line: 2
>
> Timestamp: 12/28/2012 2:40:34 PM Warning: Use of getAttributeNode() is
>   deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. Source File:
>   ~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js Line: 3

Firefox Web Console returns those two, as well as the below (which lands between the above two):

> Request URL:    ~/PartsLabor/GetPartDesc?002N02337
>   Request Method: GET
>   Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is not working? Do you get any errors in your browser's debug tool console output window for example?

Comment: if you put a break point in GetPartDesc does it get hit?  Does itemnmbr have the value you expected?

Comment: @BenTidman Put in a break point on the controller at GetPartDesc.  Doesn't break when I select the itemnmbr...

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Using Firefox.  When I look in "Web Console" and select a part, I get:

[13:58:36.938] Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. @ http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2

[13:58:37.007] GET http://localhost:10659/PartsLabor/GetPartDesc?itemnmbr=002059200++++++++++++++++++++++ [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 64ms]
--

[13:58:48.385] Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. @ http://localhost:10659/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js:3

Comment: Did you try the change I posted below?

Comment: @BenTidman I did... Doesn't appear to have changed anything as far as the results and error's I'm seeing.

Comment: Are you getting javascript errors? 404?  Can you post them?

Comment: @BenTidman Ben, The only errors I've seen (That aren't CSS related) are the ones in the comment to F. Wahl above.  I've added them to the bottom of the O.P. so that they were structured better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.  Check out the examples on [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) on how to use get().

guessing GetPartDesc is never getting hit or it's not getting the parameter that you are expecting. It will probably work if you change:

```
        $.get("/PartsLabor/GetPartDesc", $(this).val(), function (data) {
            $("#ITEMDESC").val(data);
        });
```

to:

```
        $.get("/PartsLabor/GetPartDesc", { itemnmbr: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            $("#ITEMDESC").val(data);
        });
```

But I haven't tested it.  Also I personally use the jquery .ajax method for this kind of thing.  I've never used get, though reading a little seems like what you have should work.  Anyway you can try something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '/PartsLabor/GetPartDesc',
            data: { itemnmbr: $(this).val() }
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#ITEMDESC").val(data);
        });
```

Comment: Replaced everything between <script type="text/javascript"> and </script> with the $.ajax code.  Now I receive the below on page load as well as the two java error at bottom of OP.  Don't get the 500 Internal Error now.

[15:10:29.349] TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined @ ~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js:3

Comment: hmm... that's strange.  Sounds like you have a different problem now. Does the page load at all?  are you able to hit your break point now?

Comment: The page loads with the e.nodeName java error.  The other two get thrown when I select something from the dropdown, then click OFF the dropdown (anywhere else on page).  Did not stop at my breakpoint.

Comment: Hmm, now there's some error detail... Loaded Firebug, and that 500 Internal Server Error is giving me: Server Error in '/' Application.
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'itemnmbr' of non-nullable type 'System.Char' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetPartDesc(Char)' in 'TechConnect.Controllers.PartsLaborController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: make your parameter on your controller action nullable by decalring it as char? itemnmbr.  Add logic to see if it HasValue before using it.

Comment: I thought the line `public ActionResult GetPartDesc(char itemnmbr)` declares it? The same error in Firebug under Parameters shows: **ITEMNMBR 002-00079-02**, which is the part number I chose... I also changed all the instances of itemnmbr to ITEMNMBR just to eliminate any inconsistency there.  That matches the field name in the db.  Perhaps I should ditch `char` and use `varchar`?  The db field is a `char` field, but a lot of the values in it are numeric like the one above...

Comment: no no no... :) nullable char.  like this. public ActionResult GetPartDesc(char? itemnmbr) See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: also, you know char is just a single character right?  if you want it to be multiple characters you need to declare all your properties as strings.  If you are using automatic migration with entity framework, it should see the change and tell you you need to update your DB.

Comment: hmm... I'll have to see if the program hitting the db will mess up if I mod the db.

Comment: Well I'm an idiot and I'm surprised that that took us that long.  String it is. It works like a champ now.  And now that I think about it, the db says char(61)... ie string.  Double idiot.